# rendering element via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a page that when a button is clicked I want run a method on the rails side and update the page accordingly:

Controller Method:

```
def disallow_part_for_augment
   disallowed_part = AvailableAugmentsPart.create(part_id: params[:part_id], available_augment_id: params[:id], disallow: true)
   disallowed_part.save()

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to v2_parts_url }
     format.js
   end
end
```

Ajax Method:

```
$ ->
  $('#disallow-part').click (e) ->
    console.log $(this).attr("href")
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax
      url: $(this).attr("href")
      type: 'PUT'
      //data: 
    return
```

The portion with the call to a helper method is what I want updated

```
            <td><%= au.augment.code %></td>
            <%= show_part_group_for_allowed_parts(part_group.name, @part.id, au.id) %>
            <td><%= part_group.part_category.name %></td>
```

Helper method

```
def show_part_group_for_allowed_parts(part_group_name, part_id, available_augment_id)
    html = ""

    if AvailableAugmentsPart.is_part_disallowed(part_id, available_augment_id).exists?
      html << "<td class='status color-red'>Disallowed</td>"
    else
      html << "<td>#{part_group_name}</td>"
    end
    return raw(html)
  end
```

Link to trigger event:

```
<%= link_to('DISALLOW', "disallow_part_for_augment/#{au.id}", id: 'disallow-part', class: 'btn btn-mini btn-primary', title: 'Disallow', remote: true) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `format.js` in your controller will look for the template `disallow_part_for_augment.js.erb`, and send that to the browser where it will be executed. So in there you can do what you need to do to update the page.

To easily find the part to be updated you will want to add a class or ID to it (e.g. in your helper):

```
html << "<td id='part-#{part_id}' class='status color-red'>Disallowed</td>"
```

So you can reference it from `disallow_part_for_augment.js.erb` like this:

```
$("#part-<%= @disallowed_part.part_id %>")
  .replaceWith(
    "<%= escape_javascript(show_part_group_for_allowed_parts(...)) %>");
```